Regression: negative intercept with only positive values
I'm doing a multiple linear regression on some standard deviation values, but the intercept and the coefficient for many of the predictors are negative.
Any ideas on how I should interpret the results?

The intercept is the fitted value when all predictors have a value of zero. If you are surprised by a negative intercept, that probably means that a zero does not make sense for your predictors. Negative coefficients for predictors may make sense, or be a symptom of overfitting, we would need more information to help you. What do you mean by "a regression on some standard deviation values"?

In addition to the other comment, have you considered modeling log(standard deviation)? That would ensure that the model can never predict a negative SD (even if all predictor values were 0).

@StephanKolassa I calculated the standard deviation for some economical metrics as a risk measure and I tried to predict it based on some features that might affect the risk profile of a company

@Björn, I had not thought about it, but wondering whether I would lose too much interpretability

SDs can vary a lot -- indeed you wouldn't be doing this if SD were roughly constant --  and working with a logarithmic link would often be a good idea.

Although my self-serving judgment is that you got good comments and answers, you'd get better answers by editing your question to say more. A limiting case of questions here is "I get puzzling results. What do they mean?" You're not close to that but you aren't far from it either.

Re: interpretability of a model on the log-scale, things are pretty interpretable, if you back-transform (with exponential), things are just multiplicative instead of additive.

The answer here is likely to be very simple. The intercept is the predicted outcome when all the predictors are zero. Quite often that point is not only not within the range of the data, but also not even  attainable on familiar grounds (physically, biologically, economically, whatever). So, the weight predicted for a baby of age $0$ and length $0$ and parental income $0$ is not something we really want to know.
Implausible or impossible intercepts are often met but usually ignored.
If they are troubling one answer is to shift variables. A case I often meet is a regression of something environmental or economic on calendar year for recent years, say whatever $=$ intercept $a + b$ calendar year. Here $a$ is what is predicted for year $0$ which -- setting aside the minor point that $1$ BC = BCE was followed by $1$ AD = CE -- is usually way outside the range of the data. The intercept is likely to be absurdly low or absurdly high, depending on the slope of the regression.
Here one solution is simply to shift the origin, so that (say) a regression whatever $=$ intercept $a + b$ (year $-\ 2000$) has the interpretation that the intercept is what is fitted for year $= 2000$.
John W. Tukey evidently used to talk of centercepts, not intercepts, where a centercept is within the range of the data.
A more common solution is, as said, not to worry about such an intercept. It's just a side-effect of what you're doing. However, you should still be confident that $Y = Xb$ is a good functional form for your data and purposes.

Thank you for your answer. But in that case I would have negative values only for the intercept and not the coefficients as well, correct?

The coefficients are not affected by any translation of the origin. Negative coefficients that surprise you for an outcome that should be positive may be a sign of overfitting or nonlinearity, as already mentioned. We need to know much more about your set-up to say more.

You would interpret them the same way you interpret any regression results. Although you haven't given us a lot of details, there is nothing really surprising in what you have told us.  It would really help if you gave details: What are your variables?
As Stephen notes, the intercept is the predicted value of the dependent variable when all the independent variables are 0. He points out that a 0 value for all the predictors may be unreasonable. In a comment you say your IVs are "some features" well, that doesn't help much, but you seem to be working in economics and lots of economic variables are never 0 or really close to 0.
For the parameter estimates for other variables, remember that each of them is controlling for all the other variables. Unless all your IVs are orthogonal to each other (which rarely happens except in true experiments where you control the variables -- and that is very rare in economics) then this can lead to some results that would be odd in a simple regression (one with only one IV).

For many economists. IV means instrumental variable (although the same economists should have no difficulty whatsoever in following your point). At the same time, the terminology dependent variable, independent variable has long since past its sell-by date. We may have had that conversation before.

More importantly, we were writing at the same time and unsurprisingly have the same main message.

I'm using: standard deviation of profit and as predictors things such as location of the company and company size, the the location is categorical.

OK, well, a company size of 0 is clearly nonsensical, however you are measuring it.

If the coefficients for some indicator variables are negative, that just means that the prediction for variable $= 1$ is less than that for variable $= 0$, other variables held constant.
